# I could not add item number,item price and quantity in paypal adaptive payment implementing PayPal Library for PHP CodeIgniter Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I could not add item number,item price and quantity in paypal adaptive payment implementing PayPal Library for PHP CodeIgniter Framework.

I am trying to use payapl paypal adaptive payment with PayPal Library in CodeIgniter.
I have completed simple view. But I need to add item number,item price and quantity.
This is my output images
[image]

But I want to similar this,  add See ticket,seats, item description etc, Specially I need to add item number, item price and quantity. 
[image]

I am awaiting for an affirmative response from you. How can I add those in to my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[SetPaymentOptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/)" API to include the item description,line items. But you can use this API only [embedded](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/) flow.

Comment: Which function I have to call first,

Pay_with_options or pay_chained_demo ?

Comment: not sure what function you are referring to.
But, you can call https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/ API first, then call "SetPaymentOptions" API